# obtain string from file using partial string

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I've got a file with strings like these:
file_A

```
Solyc01g094920   
Solyc01g094930
```

now I want to obtain the corresponding strings from another file that includes the numbers:
file_B

```
Solyc01g094410.2.1 
Solyc01g094820.1.2  
Solyc01g094900.1.2  
Solyc01g094910.1.1  
Solyc01g094920.2.1   
Solyc01g094930.1.2
```

i've got something working for me now because the order is preserved.
Is there a way to make it work without the linenumbers?

```
linenumber = 0

    for line in file_B:  
        if linenumber > 10 and linenumber < 100:  
            outfile.write(line)
        linenumber += 1
```

Thanks

Comment: What's `x`? Post the full code you are using

Comment: How can linenumber be both greater than **and** less than `x`?!?

Comment: the order preserve? whith which file_a or fileb

Comment: Where is `file_B` used in your code?

Comment: file_A is a section of file_B. Now i want the same names of file_A including the last numbers. These can be found in file_B. Sorry, referring to file_A in my code needs to be file_B

Comment: suggestion : use linux join: https://www.biostars.org/p/63016/

Comment: Thanks Pierre, got it working for me with python now.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = """'Solyc01g094920'   
'Solyc01g094930'"""
b = """'Solyc01g094410.2.1'  
'Solyc01g094820.1.2'  
'Solyc01g094900.1.2'  
'Solyc01g094910.1.1'  
'Solyc01g094920.2.1'
'Solyc01g094930.1.2'"""

aa = [x.strip("'") for x in a.split()]

for line in b.split():
    for aaa in aa:
        if line.startswith("'" + aaa):
            print(line)
```

Output:

```
'Solyc01g094920.2.1'
'Solyc01g094930.1.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `split()`

```
for line in file_B:  
    t = line.split('.') -- this splits string in collection
    outfile.write(t[0]) -- first variable from collection
```

Update: for Line in file_B but not in file_A:

```
for line in file_B:
    t = line.split('.')
    target = t[0]
    if target not in file_A:
         outfile.write(target)
```

Update: for only Line in file_B which are in file_A too:

```
for line in file_B:
    t = line.split('.')
    target = t[0]
    if target in file_A:
         outfile.write(target)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i want to get the strings from file_B, without using the linenumbers. Instead I would like to use the similarity of the strings.

Comment: I would like to use a method that doesn't need the linenumbers so I can apply it to other files.

Comment: Thanks but i want it the other way around. I already have the strings in file_A. Now i need some of the strings of file_B. These strings are the same except for that they contain additional numbers at the end. Somehow i need to find the corresponding strings in file_B using file_A strings.

Comment: The Above answer will give you the lines which are not in file_A and if you want corresponding 'appended code' only from the same line then .. it will be another edit, please clarify if I have missed something here..

Comment: Hey Marmik, wasn't yet what i was looking for but gave me the information how to do it. thanks for that.                            
`file_A_list = []
for line in file_A:
 line = line.strip('\n')
 file_A_list.append(line)
 

for line2 in file_B:
 t = line2.split('.')
 target = t[0]
 if target in file_A_list:
  outfile.write(line2)'

Comment: Happy that you got the answer, I have updated similar in my answer.

Comment: almost the same. i do outfile.write(line) instead of outfile.write(target) (to include the endnumbers)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

a = """'Solyc01g094920'
'Solyc01g094930'"""
b = """'Solyc01g094410.2.1'
'Solyc01g094820.1.2'
'Solyc01g094900.1.2'
'Solyc01g094910.1.1'
'Solyc01g094920.2.1'
'Solyc01g094930.1.2'"""

for n in a.splitlines():
    n = "("+n.strip("'")+".*)'" # this find the pattern lineA plus anything.
    print re.findall(n,b)
```

Output:

```
["Solyc01g094920.2.1"]
["Solyc01g094930.1.2"]
```